# Generate Multi-line List dynamically in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new in Ionic and I want to generate [Multi-line List](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#multiline-list) just like we generate list-view in Android with custom view and using Array of custom object programmatically.

Is it possible to generate Multi-line List with data from Array using TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using `virtualScroll` or `ngFor` for iterating the Array object on the view.